# Windows cmd working just sporadically

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Somehow it seems that my windows 7 cmd prompt is only working correct sporadically. If I open a new cmd I can nearly always execute applications within PATH (sometimes this doesn't work either). But after a few executions the command which worked previously stops working and cmd is telling me:

The command "java.exe" is misspelled or couldn't be found (translated from german)

After opening a new cmd, the problem is gone. Can someone explain why this happens and how I can solve this?

Comment: Version of windows? Maybe example of programs you execute and afterwards cmd doesn't work anymore? Or is it just with java.exe?

Comment: Windows is Win7 although cmd tells Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601].  `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.  

C:\Users\philipph>notepad.exe  

C:\Users\philipph>  

Second terminal  

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.  

C:\Users\philipph>notepad.exe  
Der Befehl "notepad.exe" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.`

Comment: I'm having the same problem sporadically on a Windows 2003 Server R2 Standard. My guess from the programmer's perspective is that the launching process (i.e. the shell, "Explorer") is induced to forget its environment and therefore doesn't pass it to child processes anymore. The reason could be shell extensions or any kind of DLL that can do this from within the shell process.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: It's *possible*, but according to philnate's description, it's a *running* `cmd` instance that suddenly forgets its environ, but ones created afterwards work fine again.

Comment: In this case the solution is even easier because any script can modify the environment of a running `cmd.exe` when it gets to run there. So check `PATH` before and after running the commands/scripts and then see which one is causing the issue and fix the script/program or wrap it into a script that will retain the environment ...

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED thanks that you pointed me to the problem. I thought it was caused by those apps called, but I ignored that I was calling some custom batch file which sets itself the variable path. Have changed the name of the variable and its working fine. Thanks

Comment: @philnate: `set PATH=%PATH%;new-folder` can prevent this kind of symptom.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but the path I used isn't for classpath instead of an concrete file. So this wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the PATH after java not working? May be a batch file modified the PATH.

Comment: It's recommended to write batch scripts with `setlocal` as the first command to avoid this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

try using the console and when it does work issue:

```
prompt:\> sfc /scannow
```

you will be probably asked for the Windows CD...

Maybe reverting to a previous system restore point can do the trick...

Comment: Luckily there's no need to use that heavy countermeasurement